# Save and re-use a request in a servlet filter?

Tags: java, servlets, openid, servlet-filters

I am writing an OpenID filter based on the JOID library to allow applications to transparently authenticate against our local OpenID Server. Since OpenID works via HTTP redirects, I end up losing the original request object in the process, especially if it's a POST with a data body. Is it possible to save the request object in a way that I can reuse it later in the transaction, after the user has been authenticated? Even just saving the message body itself should suffice, as I can preserve the query URL easily enough with a roundtrip redirect (by using the OpenID's return-to-url).

I want to make this completely transparent to the underlying servlets, so they behave the same whether the user went through the OpenID flow for this particular request or just has a valid/authenticated local session.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Store the data of interest (request parameters, request attributes, etc) in a [`Map`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) in session scope by an unique ID as key which you add to the return-to-url.

```
String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
DataOfInterest data = new DataOfInterest(request);
Map<String, DataOfInterest> map = (Map<String, DataOfInterest) session.getAttribute("dataOfInterest");
map.put(id, data);
returnToUrl += "?token=" + URLEncoder.encode(id, "UTF-8");
// ...
```

And then when it comes back, use [`HttpServletRequestWrapper`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequestWrapper.html) to wrap the current request wherein you override the `getParameter()` and consorts to return the original data of interest. Do this in a `Filter`.

```
String id = request.getParameter(token);
Map<String, DataOfInterest> map = (Map<String, DataOfInterest) session.getAttribute("dataOfInterest");
DataOfInterest data = map.remove(id);
chain.doFilter(new HttpServletRequestWithDataOfInterest(request, data), response);
```

The `HttpServletRequestWithDataOfInterest` can look like this:

```
public class HttpServletRequestWithDataOfInterest extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {

    private DataOfInterest data;

    public HttpServletRequestWithDataOfInterest(HttpServletRequest request, DataOfInterest data) {
        super(request);
        this.data = data;
    }

    public String getParameter(String name) {
        return data.getParameter(name);
    }

    public String[] getParameterValues(String name) {
        return data.getParameterValues(name);
    }

    // Etc, only when necessary.
}
```

---

*Note: any obvious nullcheck handling etc is up to you.*

Comment: I never knew about HttpServletRequestWrapper - sounds like just the wiring I need.

Answer (score 2):

For general purpose usage it would be more complex than save just a request body, you also need to save headers and so on.

You may check [how it's implemented in Spring Security](https://fisheye.springsource.org/browse/spring-security/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/savedrequest).

Comment: That's true, thus I was hoping to just save the old request object itself directly and short-circuit any parsing.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't save a request.  But you can have your filter create a session and add the object to session scope.  Objects that have access to the session can use any object they find.

Comment: I did the same by storing the request object to the session. But when coming back after a round-trip, found the URL(and other parameters, attributes too) for the retrieved request object from the session as NULL !! So, just stored the interested request params too session to reuse instead of the whole object - which worked

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth (and for anyone coming here in the future), after fighting with this for about another week, I ended up switching my app over to use Spring Security entirely instead of a standalone custom filter and it works great. The Spring Security framework handles a lot of the odd issues with redirects and postponed requests that I was starting to have to write on my own.

Thanks to everyone for their suggestions.